# VBA save file as predetermined name

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to pre-populate the filename in the save dialog in Word using VBA.
The code I am using now is
ThisDocument:

```
Private Sub Document_New()
  Register_Event_Handler
End Sub
```

mdiEventConnect module:

```
Dim X As New EventClassModule
Sub Register_Event_Handler()
  Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

EventClassModule class:

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave _
  (ByVal Doc As Document, _
  SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
  Cancel As Boolean)

  Dim intResponse As Integer

    intResponse = MsgBox("Do you really want to " _
    & "save the document?", _
    vbYesNo)

 If intResponse = vbNo Then
   Cancel = True
 Else:
   Dim fPth As Object
   Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

   With fPth
     .InitialFileName = "Testfile" & ".docx"
     .Title = "Bestand Opslaan"
     .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
     .Show
   End With
 End If

End Sub
```

The problem I am having right now is that the save dialog pops up as it should, but as soon as I save the file another save dialog pops up without the pre determined filename in it.

If anyone has any tips for me, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `SaveAsUi = False` near the beginning of the BeforeSave event.